# Firefox ESR 52.5.2 Auto Enable Add-On

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to force a specific add-on to always be enabled?

During certain software updates the add-on in question is automatically disabled (No idea why) and because this add-on is required to use the web applications that our users use on a daily basis. While some users call a few times and are able to remember the fix action themselves (Go into addons and enable the add-on) other users call after every-single-update and ask us to talk them through enabling it.

Is there a way to force enable this addon? I cannot seem to find a way to force add-ons to be enabled that works as most posts I can find are all the way from 2010-2015. They are pretty out of date and no longer work.

Comment: For what operating system?

Comment: Windows 7 & Window 10

Answer (score 0):

It's not that easy to force a single add-on to be enabled without affecting other addons, as there's no own configuration parameter for each extension.

To see what would be needed to modify, you can use `about:config` and compare configuration parameter `extensions.bootstrappedAddons` when a single extension is enabled and disabled: enabling an extension will add a new entry like this (without line breaks):

```
{
 "version":"x.y.z",  
 "type":"webextension",
 "descriptor":"C:\\path\\to\\the\\profile\\extensions\\{extension}.xpi",
 "multiprocessCompatible":true,
 "runInSafeMode":false,
 "dependencies":[],
 "hasEmbeddedWebExtension":false
}
```

This means that overwriting this configuration parameter would change the state for all extensions.

---

Better approach might be trying to prevent this automatic disable in your default [preference file](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences):

```
pref("extensions.autoDisableScopes", 0);
```

It's also possible to automatically enable extensions by scopes (not necessarily secure/desired):

```
pref("extensions.enabledScopes", 15);
```

Here, the number is a sum of the scope numbers, `15` meaning all i.e. `1+2+4+8`:

- `1 (SCOPE_PROFILE)`, add-on in the current profile directory.
- `2 (SCOPE_USER)`, extensions in `%appdata%\Mozilla\Extensions\`
- `4 (SCOPE_APPLICATION)`, extensions directory within the application binary directory
- `8 (SCOPE_SYSTEM)` system extension directory, N/A in Windows.